# Input layer max_pooling1d is incompatible, what is the problem?

Tags: keras, tf.keras

Dears

How to concatenate four differents tensors 1D in Keras? It output the following error:

`ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer max_pooling1d_72: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`

The error is in the last line, please help me

Example:

```
input_coder =  Input(shape=(256,1))
######################### MAIN  ##########################
output = Convolution1D(256,9,padding='same',strides=1)(input_coder)
output =LeakyReLU(alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)(output)
output = Convolution1D(256,1,padding='same',strides=1)(output)
output = Convolution1D(256,9, padding='same',strides=1)(output)
output = BatchNormalization()(output)
output = LeakyReLU(alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)(output)
output = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2))(output)
############################ INCEPTION BLOCK  ##########################
incept1 = Convolution1D(1,1,padding='same')(output)
incept1 =Flatten()(incept1)
incept2 = Convolution1D(1,1,padding='same')(output)
incept2= LeakyReLU(alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)(incept2)
incept2 = Convolution1D(1,3,padding='same')(incept2)
incept2= LeakyReLU(alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)(incept2)
incept2 =Flatten()(incept2)
incept3 = Convolution1D(1,1,padding='same')(output)
incept3= LeakyReLU(alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)(incept3)
incept3 = Convolution1D(1,5,padding='same')(incept3)
incept3= LeakyReLU(alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)(incept3)
incept3 =Flatten()(incept3)
incept4 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1)(output) # pool size in paper=3
incept4 = Convolution1D(1,1,padding='same')(incept4)
incept4 =Flatten()(incept4)
inception1=Concatenate()([incept4,incept1, incept2, incept3])
inception1 = BatchNormalization()(inception1)
inception1 = LeakyReLU(alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)(inception1)
inception1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2))(inception1)
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

question seems to be little confusing about concatenating tensors,from my understanding of it you are facing in-compaitable layer issue, this can be corrected by expanding dimensions in last axis of inception1 layer.

```
inception1 = LeakyReLU(alpha=leaky_relu_alpha)(inception1)
import tensorflow as tf
inception1 = tf.expand_dims(inception1, axis = -1) # expand dimension along last axis
inception1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2))(inception1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
I have applied the solution you provided but the model crash when it built.!! and RAM resources is always not enough.

Comment: if RAM is running out, then its probably because 1. if you have more parameters in your model or 2.you have loaded entire training data into RAM. possible solutions would be if 1. then reduce model parameters or opt for a cloud based VM, if 2. you might want to look into data generators for feeding data to the model, ex : python generator or subclassing keras.sequence

Comment: i think its mostly because of more parameters,since it is crashing during build.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a matter of computing resources. My code needs 32G of RAM.